# How to call a javascript function declared in Crossrider "background.js" by clicking a button from my website page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, browser, crossrider

How to call a javascript function declared in Crossrider "background.js" by clicking a button from my website page?

I have a button input in my website page "http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx". I also have defined a function "myExtensionFunction" in [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com/) [a cross-browser extension framework] "background.js" scope that accepts a javascript object / JSON as parameter. Is it possible to pass a javascript object / JSON as parameter and call this function by clicking on the button in my website page and vice versa? If so, how? If not, why?

I know from this tutorial below, "how to pass the value of a page variable to the extension scope?", but could not solve the above problem.
http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/howto_get_page_variable

I tried the code below, but gave me the 
alert 'function does not exist!', as expected, 
as it could not find the function defined in the 
Crossrider browser extension [extension.js file]

```
Javascript file:
---------------

var lxnsT = [];
lxnsT.push({ "u_n": "MegaSearches", "u_a": "URL" });

function myExtFn() {
    if (typeof jsOpenSession == 'function') {
        myExtensionFunction(lxnsT);
    } else {
        alert('function does not exist!');
    }
}

HTML file:
---------------
<button id="myExtFnId" onclick="myExtFn()"> My Button </button>
```

Comment: <button onclick="myExtensionFunction()"> press me </button>

Comment: @CatalinSterian: that's irrelevant, this is extension code with different scopes.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this button? In Crossrider, there is the background scope and the extension page scope -- what you're attempting to do will affect what you should do.

Comment: I want to allow my website users who has installed my Crossrider browser extension to import all the bookmarks they have in local browser by clicking a button on my website. I already did this by clicking a button in the extension itself, but want to enable the users to do it directly from the website using the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you can achieve your goal by using your *extension.js* file as a conduit between your page and the background scope. You have to do this because the background scope does not have direct access to the HTML page scope.

To implement the scenario, add the **[CrossriderAPI](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/CrossriderAPI.events)** library to your page using it to show the button when the extension is available and configure the button's click handler to send the object to the extension scope, as follows:

**HTML** file:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>.hidden {display: none;}</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://w9u6a2p6.ssl.hwcdn.net/plugins/javascripts/crossriderAPI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Replace XXXXX with the extension id
  var extId = "XXXXX";

  // Once the page is ready
  $(function() {
    CrossriderAPI.isAppInstalled(extId, function(isInstalled) {
      // Displays button if the extension is installed and set click handler
      console.log('Page:: Extension installed? ' + isInstalled);
      if (isInstalled) {
        console.log('Page:: Showing button and adding click');
        $("#myExtFnId").toggleClass("hidden").click(function() {
          $('body').fireExtensionEvent('execBgFunc', {fn:'myBgFn', data:'my data'});
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myExtFnId" class="hidden">My Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In your *extension.js* file, bind an event handler to receive the object from the page and then send it via [messaging](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message) to the background scope, as follows:

**extension.js** file:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  $('body').bindExtensionEvent('execBgFunc',
    function(e, data) {
      console.log('Extn:: Bind Received: ' + appAPI.JSON.stringify(data));
      appAPI.message.toBackground(data);
  });
});
```

Finally, in the *background.js* file, use a message listener to receive the data and execute the required function, as follows:

**background.js** file:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.fn === 'myBgFn')
      console.log('Bg:: Received data: ' + appAPI.JSON.stringify(msg.data));
  });
});
```

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]